# inversion of the sum

Tags: digital-communications

In the article [*Analysis of the Performance of a Non-Coherent
Large Scale SIMO System Based on M-DPSK
Under Rician Fading*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiF79aX07ftAhUjxIUKHQxyALMQFjAJegQIDBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eurasip.org%2FProceedings%2FEusipco%2FEusipco2017%2Fpapers%2F1570346299.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3k0yctXNFQ3XW3PFqDkVd1) Fig.1:

[image: figure 1]

I would like to know if we could invert the block of the sum with the symbol detection. That is to say, make a symbol detection on each antenna and after the sum where the bit $0$ is defined by $-1$. I would like a mathematically justified answer

Comment: You should point out which equation that you are talking about in the paper, so that someone wouldn't have to read the whole thing.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. A link to the article is OK for context, but one shouldn't have to go read it.